# Validate on an iso code or empty

Tags: python, regex

I want the following values to validate:

```
'en', 'us', 'usa', ''
```

Essentially, it can be any two/three letters or an empty string. What would be the correct regular expression for this? So far I have:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a string with 0, 2, or 3 letters, use

```
import re

re.match('^(?:[A-Za-z]{2,3})?$', …)
```

`[A-Za-z]{2,3}` means "two to three letters".

`(?:…)?` means that what is inside the parentheses is optional.

`^…$` ensures that longer strings are not accepted.

Comment: I'm using xsd, which doesn't support `?` as well as normal python regex does (whenever I've tried using `?` it gives me an error). Is there another way to do that without a `?` ? That's why I'm currently using the `|` at the end of it: `re.match(r'[A-Za-z]{2}|','')`

Comment: XSD is a completely separate topic. Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: 'usa' or 'us' is an acceptable one. It is 2- or 3-letter iso code.